# Commenting end of function

Tags: php, comments

Is it good practice in PHP to comment the end of a function, right next to the closing brace?

e.g.

```
} // end display_items
```

Comment: It is a matter of coding style. I'm not sure it brings a lot.

Comment: if the braces are aligned correctly the function end should be obvious.

Comment: And most IDEs will have folding and hinting to show the block. This is more useful for when you break up the function into separate <?php ?> tags and output HTML, so nesting can be confusing without them. I think this is probably more useful for branching (if, endif) and looping than function calls however.

Comment: @AramKocharyan And I would say if you have to break `<?php ?>` _inside_ a function, you are almost certainly engaging in one or more bad practices.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski wordpress.org does it throughout their code. You can also use heredocs, but I find having HTML in raw form is better than having it in a string and worrying about escaping quotes. However, for short segments using double quotes and parsing variables within is useful.

Comment: @AramKocharyan "Wordpress does it that way" is very often a reason to look elsewhere.  Don't model what you do on what wordpress does.  In a proper MVC architecture, you won't find yourself breaking `<?php ?>` inside functions very often, if ever.

Comment: Certainly, I wouldn't be using PHP in an enterprise architecture to begin with :) but good points

Comment: Speak of the devil, it seems to be a common issue! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923105/php-code-inside-html-or-html-inside-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good practise is to always indent properly, and then usually there would be no need for such comments